# fopen with username and password security

Tags: php, authentication, fopen

I am using flatfile databases (have to) and am putting an apache `basic_auth` on the folder which I will then access via PHP's `fopen()` with the username and password contained within the url, e.g:

```
fopen("http://username:password@domain.com/protectedDir/file.txt","r");
```

I am just wondering how safe this is in terms of prying eyes, as I know `POST` and any other requests can be snooped on by the user but will the user be able to see the url that `fopen()` requested to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL is not visible to the user by default. However, it may show up in an error message, for example when domain.com is temporarily unreachable. Disable showing of errors to the user.

Secondly, it would be advisable to use HTTPS to send the username and password encrypted over the network, instead of in plaintext.

Edit: PHP hides username and password in the error message:

> PHP Warning:  fopen(http://...@domain.com/protectedDir/file.txt):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found

Comment: If the SSL certificate is self signed will this prompt the user or function as normal?